# "c'est" or "il est" with adjective and preposition

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, prépositions

> (a) Ce livre, c'est difficile à lire.
>
> (b) Ce livre, c'est difficile à le lire.
>
> (c) Ce livre, il est difficile à le lire.
>
> (d) Ce livre, il est difficile de le lire.

Which of the four expressions is/are correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Il y a plusieurs difficultés: il peut représenter plusieurs choses, et difficile peut s'employer avec de ou à.**

Ce livre est difficile **à** lire (difficile à comprendre, à acheter, etc.). Le COD de lire est livre. **Difficile est suivi de à**

Il est difficile **de** lire ce livre (d'acheter cette écharpe, ...). Ce qui est difficile est la forme infinitive qui suit. **Difficile est suivi de de**

(a) Ce livre, c'est difficile à lire.

Expression correcte, mais qui sonne mal: c=cela. Ce pronom est plus englobant. Préférer Il:

> Ce livre, il est difficile à lire (forme c corrigée)

(b) Ce livre, c'est difficile à le lire.

Expression incorrecte. remarque précédente + mauvaise préposition : difficile est employé avec de, sous la forme: difficile de le lire.

> Ce livre, c'est difficile de le lire.

```
(c) Ce livre, il est difficile à le lire.
```

Forme incorrecte.

Soit il représente le livre, et on doit dire: il est difficile à lire.

Soit il est un pronom indéfini (équivalent de cela), et on doit dire il est difficile de le lire.

```
(d) Ce livre, il est difficile de le lire.
```

Forme correcte. dans ce cas, *il* est équivalent à *cela*

**Forme la plus simple:**

> Ce livre est difficile à lire.

**Forme insistante:**

> Ce livre, il est difficile à lire.
>
> Ce livre, c'est difficile de le lire.

Comment: (a) is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

First, none of those is very good, esp. in writing - the following would be better:

> Ce livre est difficile à lire.

Of course, some of the expressions you give will be heard when speaking, but introducing the subject, then re-introducing it with *il* or *ce* is considered redundant and poor style at least when writing.

That being said:

- (a) unsure, doesn't sound good, probably incorrect in fact.
- (b) is not possible. That *à/le* combination is incorrect.
- (c) is also not possible.
- (d) is possible. The redundant subject could be a problem, but nothing else to question in that sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> (a) *Ce livre, c'est difficile à lire.*

Incorrect, might be heard but should be: *Ce livre, **il est** difficile à lire*
or ***les*** livres, c'est difficile à lire.

> (b) *Ce livre, c'est difficile à le lire.*

Incorrect but can be heard in lazy spoken French. Should be: *Ce livre, c'est difficile **de** le lire.*

> (c) Ce livre, il est difficile à le lire.

Incorrect, unused.

> (d) Ce livre, il est difficile de le lire.

Correct. Equivalent to *Il est difficile de lire ce livre*. More formal than *ce livre, il est difficile à lire* and *ce livre, c'est difficile de le lire*.

Note that all these sentences are using "left [dislocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dislocation_(syntax))" which is very common in spoken French where it is often preferred to the formal/academic: *Ce livre est difficile à lire* or *lire ce livre est difficile*. See also [*Dislocation et conjugaison en français contemporain* by **Alain Berrendonner**](https://praxematique.revues.org/779)

Note that dislocation is not a novelty. Unlike in English where it is rare and frowned upon, this expressive figure of style has always been used in French and was already present in Latin.

> *Li quens Rollant, il est mult irascut.* → *Le comte Rolland, il est très en colère.* Chanson de Rolland, 11th century
>
> *Le nez de Cléopâtre, s'il eût été plus court, toute la face du monde aurait changé* Pascal, 17th century
>
> *Ils sont fous, ces Romains.*, René Goscinny, Asterix
>
> *Le changement, c'est maintenant.* François Hollande's slogan, 2012

Comment: Question 1. Would *Ce livre, c'est un roman* or *Ce livre, c'est un Balzac* be OK? 2. For (d), does *il* refer to *Ce livre* or *de le lire* or do we call it an expletive? 3. What is the subject of (d), *Ce livre* or *il* or *de le lire*? 4. Similarly in *Ce livre, c'est difficile de le lire*, which is the subject, *Ce livre* or *ce* or *de le lire*? Thank you.

Comment: I also asked this question: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24763/il-vs-ce-in-referring-to-an-event-or-idea

Comment: @Catomic - 1. yes, that's a different situation, and it is now possible. 2. _il_ refers to _le lire_, you could say: _ce livre, le lire est difficile_ (quite uncommon, but grammatically correct). 3. see 2. 4. _le lire_, by the same construction: _le lire est difficile_.

Comment: @jlliagre - excellentes références. Mais ces dislocations, je ne suis pas un grand fan. Ces dislocations, vraiment, ça ne sonne pas bien a mes oreilles.